# Spreading $r$ distinct objects to $n$ distinct baskets, calculate the expected value of a random variable

Tags: probability

Studying for my combinatorics exam and this question came out in a previous exam and couldn't solve it.

> Let $r$ and $n$ be positive integers, and let $ \langle \Omega , \operatorname{Pr} \rangle $ be our probability space, where $\Omega$ is the collection of all the distributions of $r$ distinct objects to $n$ distinct baskets and $\operatorname{Pr}$ is uniform distribution. Let $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb N$ be a random variable such that for all $\omega \in \Omega, f(\omega)$ is equal to the number of baskets that are not empty that are achieved from the distribution $\omega$. Calculate the expected value of $f$.

Comment: Let $\langle \Omega,\operatorname{Pr}\rangle$ be what?

Comment: our probability space, sorry, edited.

Comment: And what is an equal distribution? Is that like a uniform one?

Comment: Yes! I just didn't find the correct word :D

Comment: By the way, I solved it in a way (not sure if its correct) and got that the expected value of the number of non-empty baskets is $1$. is it logical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f=f_1+\cdots+f_n$, where 
$$
f_i=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if basket $i$ is not empty}\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}.
$$
Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[f]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[f_i].
$$
Now, $f_i$ only takes two values: 0 and 1. So,
$$
\mathbb{E}[f_i]=0\cdot P(\text{basket $i$ is empty})+1\cdot P(\text{basket $i$ is not empty}),
$$
and therefore
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[f_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(\text{basket $i$ is not empty}).
$$
The probability that basket $i$ is empty is precisely the probability that all of the objects land in the other $n-1$ baskets; hence
$$
P(\text{basket $i$ is empty})=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^r.
$$
So, the probability that it is not empty is
$$
P(\text{basket $i$ is not empty})=1-P(\text{basket $i$ is empty})=1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^r.
$$
So, the expected number of non-empty baskets is
$$
\mathbb{E}[f]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^r\right)=n\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^r\right).
$$
As a quick check: if $r=1$, then there is no randomness in the number of non-empty baskets: it is always $1$. This matches the above expectation.

Comment: Good and all, but the question says that $f$ is the number of baskets that are ***not*** empty

Comment: Whoops!  Good call.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Haha! no problem. waiting.

Comment: There, fixed it.

Comment: one more thing. Why is $E[f_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} {P(\text{basket i is not empty})}$? Isn't $E[f_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} {f_i(\omega) \cdot P(\text{basket i is not empty})} = n (1 - (\frac{n-1}{n})^r )$?

Comment: I mean it is $\cdot n$ because we sum it $n$ times? That is the definition of expected value, no?

Comment: One sec, I'll add an explanation

Comment: Okay, how's that?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It may interest you that this is an enumeration problem that may be solved using symbolic combinatorics with ordinary generating functions. We first calculate the expected number of empty baskets.

The generating function for the pattern repertoire is
$$ f(v; u_1,\ldots u_r) = v - 1 + (1+u_1)(1+u_2)\cdots(1+u_r)$$
where $v$ represents the empty configuration.

Putting these into $n$ distinct baskets gives
$$ g(v; u_1,\ldots u_r) = f(v; u_1,\ldots u_r)^n.$$
Now we have $$g(1; 1, \ldots 1) = 2^{rn}$$ which reflects the fact that initially we assign a subset of the $r$ objects to every basket.

The next step is to extract the generating function where each object ocurrs only once.
This is
$$[u_1 u_2 \cdots u_r]  (v - 1 + (1+u_1)(1+u_2)\cdots(1+u_r))^n \\
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (v-1)^{n-q} 
[u_1 u_2 u_3 \cdots u_r](1+u_1)^q(1+u_2)^q(1+u_3)^q\cdots(1+u_r)^q \\
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (v-1)^{n-q} 
q[u_2 u_3 \cdots u_r](1+u_2)^q(1+u_3)^q\cdots(1+u_r)^q \\
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (v-1)^{n-q} 
q^2[u_3 \cdots u_r](1+u_3)^q\cdots(1+u_r)^q \\
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (v-1)^{n-q} q^r.$$
Putting $v=1$ in the above yields the total number of configurations, which is
$n^r.$ (Only the term for $q=n$ contributes.)

For the expected value we differentiate by $v$ and set $v=1,$ getting
$$ \left.\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q} (n-q) (v-1)^{n-q-1} q^r\right|_{v=1}
= {n\choose n-1} (n-(n-1)) (n-1)^r =
n (n-1)^r.$$

The conclusion is that the expected value of the number of empty baskets is given by
$$ \frac{n (n-1)^r}{n^r} = n\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^r.$$
Note that this goes to $n/e$ when $r=n.$

It then follows that the expected number of baskets that are not empty is given by
$$ n - n\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^r =
n\left(1-\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^r \right),$$
confirming the first answer that was given.